# Custom Event / Action after checkin in TFS

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, devops

How can I execute a Powershell script at each check in into TFS source control for a particular file or directory?

This is different than custom check in policies. This is a post check in event. .

Comment: It's not supported as Daniel said, you can submit a user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) to suggest the feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. TFVC does not support anything resembling what you'd like to do.

Answer (score -1):

A bit more involved, but you could consider using [service hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/hooks/overview) and configure a [web hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/service-hooks/services/webhooks) to publish events.